# Python and Django 1.7 I need to change the source of some of the supporting modules

Tags: python, django, pip, monkeypatching

I've just upgraded to Django 1.7 and I've found that a couple of the modules we rely on which are installed by pip have small issues.

I've played on a test box and found that each of these modules only needs a couple of lines to be changed to support Django 1.7. Both have import errors which are easily fixed.

What would be the best way to make a temporary patch to these files?

Ideally I would like the fix to live with my project until updated modules appear and I can remove it. We're running puppet on the production systems so I could just overwrite the two files with new versions but this seems too easy to lose track of. Monkey patching might work, but as they are import errors I'm not sure how to cut this out before it fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost everyone's on GitHub these days. Fork the repos, make your changes, and point your requirements file to your forks.

You might even want to make pull requests back to the maintainers, which will help these issues be fixed even more quickly.

Comment: Yes this sounds promising, Will investigate now